# How to add user tracking authorization, in ionic cordova

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, user-tracking

I deploy my app to apple store and they reject because
"Starting with iOS 14.5, apps on the App Store need to receive the user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before collecting data used to track them. This requirement protects the privacy of App Store users."

Ionic version 5.0

[image]

Comment: Did you add the Privacy metadata in the AppStore? Did you add code to handle the privacy authorization, both allow and reject?

Comment: I already add he Privacy metadata in the AppStore. But I cannot find a code the privacy authorization in ionic, could you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Read: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/
then go to: https://swiftsenpai.com/development/get-ready-apptrackingtransparency/

to see code example for implementation

Comment: Thank you, but I use ionic to implement my mobile application. Do you have an example code for ionic or are there other way to do this?